# Errors in Chrome and Safari using linkedin 'follow company' button for logged in users

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, linkedin-api

I generated a linkedin follow button from the Linkedin '[follow company plugin generator](https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/follow-company)' and inserted the scripts directly on into a Wordpress menu item:

```
<script src="https://platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"> lang: en_US</script>
<script type="IN/FollowCompany" data-id="4833942"></script>
```

For users who are not signed in, the button works as it should by opening up a new window to allow the user to sign in.

However, in Safari and Chrome, for logged in users, when the user clicks on the button, instead of changing to 'following' as it does in firefox and IE, and eventually turning into a link to the company page, the button does nothing when clicked on and appears broken.

These are the errors I noticed in the browser console when using the pop up login form in Chrome:

```
platform.linkedin.com/js/xdrpc.html?v=0.0.2000-RC8.61005-1429#xdm_e=http%3A…&xdm_p=1&target=li_gen_1496756696673_0&width=600&height=400&mode=wrapper:1 Refused to display 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/follow/submit?id=4833942&fl=start&src=btn&…BM6Ym3Je&csrfToken=ajax%3A7822936824733829906&trk=cws-btn-follow-0-0&ajax=' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

GET https://www.linkedin.com/company/follow/submit?id=4833942&fl=start&src=btn&…BM6Ym3Je&csrfToken=ajax%3A7822936824733829906&trk=cws-btn-follow-0-0&ajax= net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE
```